# Chrome Dev Tools very slow to respond in large web app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a large, javascript heavy web app that I am working on. I am experiencing very slow response times from Chrome Dev Tools for XHR responses and console loggging (3-5 secs). The actual app is running fast and responsive, only dev tools looks like it is suffering.

**Does anyone have any idea why Chrome Dev Tools is becoming sluggish as my app grows?**

Comment: I'm currently experiencing this issue while working with Dojo. The weird thing is that it only happens with the compressed version of Dojo. Working with the source version works fine. I would have supposed the problem should happen the other way around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Devtools are like any other debugger; they hook into the normal processing flow of an application, and store quite a bit more information than is normally required. This is much more work than simply rendering the page without debugging enabled, so it will indeed be slower.

That said, 3 seconds to respond to `console.log` seems high. I'd suggest that you first test the application in a [nightly version of WebKit](http://nightly.webkit.org/). If it's responsive in WebKit, but not in Chrome, please file a bug against the inspector via http://new.crbug.com/ along with any information you can provide about what scenario causes the slowness.

If it's equally sluggish in WebKit, please file a bug against WebKit's Inspector component: https://bugs.webkit.org/enter_bug.cgi

Either way, post the bug ID here, and I'll see that it's triaged into the correct team.

Comment: Firefox/Firebug are much more responsive when debugging the same large page that Chrome's debugger chokes on. And I love Chrome!

Answer (score 5):

I "fixed" the slow chrome developer tool by (under SOURCES tab)

- clearing the "watch" list that accumulated over time...
- clearing all the "snippets", i had dozens as well...

Not sure which of both made the most difference, but it certainly made a difference

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but it may help someone landing here later like I did.

Using Chrome 46.x/47.x on Linux (RHEL 7), none of the proposed solutions worked for me. What did work was to disable the setting "Use hardware acceleration when available", in the advanced browser settings.

I noticed in the process monitor/list that the Chrome renderer was taking up a lot of CPU, even putting a breakpoint or stepping throught statements in the debugger would take 10+ seconds!

Might be worth a shot.

Comment: Please don't post link only answers to other Stack Overflow questions. Instead, vote/flag to close as duplicate, or, if the question is not a duplicate, tailor the answer to this specific question.

Comment: Ok, should I take the answer out entirely? It's not exactly a duplicate, and it's already linked to the other question.

Comment: It's linked because you posted the link here, it will unlink when you remove the answer I think. May be better to copy the answer but edit it so it's a good fit here

Comment: Did you just -1 my answer?

Comment: I did not, why do you ask?

Comment: Never mind, I don't have time for this, I only post when I think my answer would be helpful, I edited the answer as you asked.

Comment: Seemed to help me in 2020 on Linux Mint 19.3, Chrome v. 87.

Answer (score 0):

Undock the developer tools into separate window. 
In my case, it's work.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this also, to the point where stepping through code using the chrome debugger was just so slow it took hours away from my productive development time.  In watching the CPU utilization when debugging in chrome I would see it use up to as much at 40% of all 4 cores of my processor.  I tried everything to no avail.  Finally, I tried making the browser window of the page I was debugging as small as I could without losing any of the required view and miraculously it solved the problem.  So, now I keep my debugger window popped out in a separate window, and make the window of the page I am debugging as small as I can and my debugging experience is very fast again.  I have tested this over a period of weeks and it has held out.  Hope this helps someone.